# Preserve HTTP_HOST for matching URLs only

Tags: apache-http-server, reverse-proxy

Apache mod_proxy allows to discard the original value of the HTTP_HOST header, I need to preserve that for a group of URLs, how can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, [ProxyPreserveHost](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypreservehost) is valid in 'directory' context. This means you can put it inside a `<Location>` or `<LocationMatch>` tag:

```
ProxyPass http://example/
<Location "/">
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</Location>
<Location "/special/">
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
</Location>
```

If you prefer:

```
<Location "/">
    ProxyPass http://example/
    ProxyPreserveHost On
</Location>
<Location "/special/">
    ProxyPass http://example/
    ProxyPreserveHost Off
</Location>
```

Comment: if I am not misstaken ProxyPreserveHost should appear before ProxyPass. I will give it a try, thanks.

Comment: Then you can put ProxyPass inside the `<Location>` blocks, too. But I don't think it will be necessary; the order of `Proxy*` directives doesn't seem to be particularly important.